# Java could not find XML resource bundle

Tags: java, xml, resourcebundle

```
src/java
src/resource/foo/messages.xml
                 messages_fr.xml

ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("foo.messages", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name foo.messages, locale en
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1581)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1396)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:854)
```

If they are *.properties, no problems.

How to load XML resource bundles?

Comment: You can't just make things up. The correct name for that resource is not `"foo.messages"` but `"/foo/messages.xml"`: however `ResourceBundle` doesn't understand XML anyway.

Comment: @user207421 Actually a ResourceBundle name is like a class name, so `foo.messages` is correct.  The problem, as you and Stephen pointed out, is the XML part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Java SE `ResourceBundle.getBundle(...)` only understands loading of resource bundles implemented as Java classes or ".properties" files.

If you want to load a `ResourceBundle` from an XML file, you need to provide a custom `ResourceBundle.Control` implementation that implements the resource search and loading strategies.

There is an example in the `ResourceBundle.Control` [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html); look for "Example 2".

---

I briefly searched for a 3rd-party implementation of an XML `ResourceBundle` provider, but I couldn't find anything generic.

<sup>(Asking recommendations is off-topic anyway.)</sup>